# How to write HQL Insert query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am struggling to write a HQL query for inserting a new record in a table. I have seen some of insert query as below but I don't want insert data from another table as below code.

```
String hql = "INSERT INTO Employee(firstName, lastName, salary)"  + 
             "SELECT firstName, lastName, salary FROM old_employee";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Rows affected: " + result);
```

For example I have a table "User" with three fields like name, age, number and I have entity for this user table. what will be the insert query for this?

Comment: You can't insert using the old-fashioned SQL way of `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...`, because it is not supported in HQL. You'd **have** to use Hibernate object mapping to do the insert (or raw SQL if you can expose it).

Comment: @ShotgunNinja that is a good advice, but you can force it using `createNativeQuery().setParameter().executeUpdate()` if needed, then you have to cast properly column values by yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In HQL, only the INSERT INTO … SELECT … is supported; there is no INSERT INTO … VALUES. HQL only support insert from another table.

So query INSERT from SELECT is possible like this

```
Query query = session.createQuery("insert into Stock(stock_code, stock_name)" +
                "select stock_code, stock_name from backup_stock");
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Got from [here secion 4](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/)

If you have values and Entity just  call

```
MyEntity e=new MyEntity();
e.setXXXX(the XXX values);
save(e);
```

Answer (score 4):

`HQL` doesn't support such `INSERT`s so you have to do this by creating and persisting new entity.

You can read about it [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html).

> Only the INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... form is supported. You cannot specify explicit values to insert.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(any, columns, you, want);
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();

session.save(foo); //Here you have the magic

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Just make sure you add all the values set as "not null", or you´ll get a nullException.

Answer (score -1):

HQL supports only the INSERT INTO……… SELECT……… ; there is no chance to write INSERT INTO………..VALUES, i mean while writing the insert query, we need to select values from other table, we can’t insert our own values manually.

Comment: This is more or less just a repeat of some of the existing answers.