# Why the inserting explicit values is not allowed in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

As it mentioned in [Hibernate ORM 5.2.13.Final User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_hql_syntax_for_insert):

> Only the `INSERT INTO …​ SELECT …`​ form is supported. You cannot specify explicit values to insert.

Is the reasoning behind it elaborated by official sources? Is there any certain limitation that interferes a support of the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` form in HQL?

Comment: Although this question may be a bit speculative, I guess the reasoning behind it may be due to the fact that your HQL abstracts your db into your Bean Objects, thus prefer to require one to pass values to the insert by subqueries (as the Insert will expect them to match the definition of your hibernate schema)

Comment: see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745041/inserting-data-in-one-table-using-hql-in-hibernate/12745176  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653692/how-to-write-hql-insert-query

Comment: Thanks, @LyjuIEdwinson! The referenced questions are quite related, unfortunately, they don't elaborate to the subject.

Comment: @see SJuan76 answer from first link, I think probably this is the reason

Comment: There is a similar question in the official source code (HQL-SQL ANTLR4 grammar) - https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/43ce347c0c47a64500b8f7ff748cb5413e37ac49/hibernate-core/src/main/antlr/hql-sql.g#L302

Comment: @yegodm , thanks for the link! That's kind of funny that the referred line age is 11 years and the questions is still there.

Comment: Actually, here is the original task - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-595. Not much info there though.

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason why DML-style operations have been introduced is the ability to process multiple records in the database at the expense of one (or just a few in some cases involving entity hierarchies) real SQL statement. This way we can avoid fetching all affected data in-memory to perform equivalent logic using CRUD operations on single entities (rows).

Basically this allows us to use familiar `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements from the SQL world in cases where it is needed, while still utilizing all the benefits of HQL/JPQL.

`insert ... select` also serves that purpose, while `insert ... values` would provide no benefit comparing to simply persisting an entity instance.

Comment: There might be a benefit, for an instance, possibility to write a generic data migration script, that would be comparatively easy in HQL for some cases. Perhaps, there are multiple interesting use-cases for insert values facility that don't contradict a philosophy of the Hibernate framework.

Comment: @PavelRyzhov Sure, like in any framework, a missing feature could come handy in some cases. I just noted that the offered set of DML-style operations is consistent in regards to an ability to perform bulk operations in the database with a single command.